# How can I first set a MenuItem sensitive and then insensitive again? Python GTK

Tags: python, gtk

How is it possible with GTK to set a menu item insensitive after clicked, but make it sensitive again, after something about 5 seconds.
If I do something like this, it doesn't work (I have no idea why not)

```
self.shutdown_item.connect("activate",self.shutdown)
self.shutdown_item.connect("activate",self.sensitiveshutdown)


def sensitiveshutdown(self,widget):
    shutdown_item.set_sensitive(False)
    time.sleep(5)
    shutdown_item.set_sensitive(True)
```

doesn't work. It freezes the gui for 5 seconds but the button stays sensitive.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way about as @unwind pointed out is a time-out (you need to import `gobject`:

```
self.shutdown_item.connect("activate",self.shutdown)
self.shutdown_item.connect("activate",self.sensitiveshutdown)


def sensitiveshutdown(self, widget):
    self.shutdown_item.set_sensitive(False)
    gobject.timeout_add(5000, self.reviveShutDown)

def reviveShutDown(self):
    self.shutdown_item.set_sensitive(True)
    return False
```

Comment: even better is to add an `return(False)` to the `reviveShutDown(self)` to cancel the `add_timeout`

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop the entire program, GTK+ needs to get to run its main loop in order to service the UI.

You should use a [timeout](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TimeoutsIOAndIdleFunctions.html#sec-Timeouts).